# How to re-size add/remove from list controls in window's form to provide anchoring like behavior

Tags: winforms, datagridview, resize, anchor, dock

I want to anchor below datagridviews to top, left, right & down in a way that they don't over lap when the size of form is increased or decreased. `Dock` and `Anchor` both don't seem to provide any solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to have a `TableLayoutPanel` handle that.  Three columns, middle column is fixed (Absolute), the outside columns would be based on percentage (50% each).

The `DataGridView` controls would then be dock-filled into each side column.

Or just handle the layout yourself in the form's Resize event.

Comment: added a panel for the middle column to act as a <div>, worked perfectly thanks!